# How we can deploy django app on cpanel with uvicorn server?

Tags: python, django, cpanel, uvicorn

I would like to deploy a Django application on a cloud server using CPanel. The issue is that I cannot find any articles which describe the process of deploying Django applications with Uvicorn on CPanel.

Comment: Django documentation has a section on how to work with Uvicorn https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/asgi/uvicorn/ . Also there an article about it https://medium.com/@pyzimos/deploying-django-web-application-using-cpanel-6687b8057439

Comment: I know very well how we can use uvicorn, but I didn't found proper documentation for deploying a django app with uvicorn on cpanel